# server configuration in java apps for services in kubernetes

Tags: java, service, kubernetes, minikube

I've got a problem concerning configuration settings in a couple of java apps.

I'm using **minikube version: v0.21.0** and **docker for mac**.

I dockerized all the apps, but the communication part between the apps is what is troubling me.

Since I've got that the applications need to communicate together through the server.url option (in the **application.propertions** for java) I'm not sure how to make that work.

The main app has also an **angular** frontend, in which I have to define the url of the two server java apps.

I know that apps in k8 communicate through **services** (with their virtual IP), and I'v done that for each app.

But in the front end app (**config.js**)

```
angular.module('app').constant("CONFIG", {
      app1_server_URL: "http://app1:8080/app1/",
      app2_server_URL: "http://app2:8095/"
});
```

So, when I get to the front end page, when I try to log in, through the chrome console, it tries to go to http://app1:8080/app1/, but is says the app can't be found? Is seems that the DNS resolving cant find the service named
**app1**? Is resolves the DNS (when I look through my browser) but it looks for http://app1:8080/app1/ outside of the cluster?

And if I make a service for all my apps that looks something like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app1
  labels:
    app: app1
spec:
  selector:
    app: app1
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 8080
    name: http
```

Can I write in the java **application properties** that the url can be reached like this:

```
server.url=http://app1
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong so any advice would be helpful.

Tnx,
Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your angular application is a frontend application. That means that the code gets executed on the browser of the user. So requests from the angular application to the java applications **come from outside the Kubernetes cluster**.

But you have created a kubernetes `Service` without specifying the `ServiceType`, which will create a `ClusterIP` kind of `Service`. This kind of service won't allow requests coming from outside the cluster, like requests from a frontend application.
You need a way to allow traffic coming from the outside of the cluster. There are several ways of achieving that, depending on your needs. The `NodePort` service type exposes the service on each node’s IP at a static port.

Let's assume that you create the following `Service`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app1
  labels:
    app: app1
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: app1
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80 # Port exposed by Pods behind the Service
    port: 8080 # Port used when connecting from inside the cluster
    nodePort: 30140 # Port used when connecting from outside the cluster
    name: http
```

That way, your angular application could send requests to http://192.168.99.100:30140, or whatever your minikube ip's and whatever port has been allocated as the `NodePort` (30140 in this example).

There are other ways of getting traffic into the cluster apart from `Services`, like using the `Ingress` object.

Comment: Hi fiunchinho, I did made a service type NodePort, but I erased it for debugging - wow tnx for the advice. So Instead of using app1_server_URL: "http://app1:8080/app1/" I should use app1_server_URL: "http://myminikubeIP:8080/app1/" to get it to work? But for cluster communication between the java apps the configuration stuff like server.url=http://app1 should also work (app1 being the service for another app)

Comment: Exactly. If you change the service from ClusterIP to NodePort, it will allow traffic coming to myminikubeIP:8080, but also communications between app1 and app2 will keep working as usual.

Comment: Hm, since the port 8080 is the exposed port of the pod not the service(NodePort), I still have to set a targetPort in the service configuration and then hardcode it in the config.js file...

Comment: Just want to add an extra point here. As far as I know, the default NodePort range is 30000-32767. if you want to have the different range you need to alter it manually.It's recommend that NodePort should not be conflicted with other system service port that's why the default range is higher.